# How to change the default behavior of ms-graph of replacing file if it exist?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

REST API of MS Graph show that I can upload a file (driveitem) with the default behavior of replace when the file exists. And I can set fail to rename options. My problem is when I use SDK for `C#` that I don't find how to change the behavior. Could you help me how to do it?

```
await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["{item-id}"]
    .Request()
    .PutAsync(Stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a stream of data so a specific `{item-id}` so the API isn't making any evaluation of the filename, it only validates that the `DriveItem` with the specified `Id` is available. If you want to rename a file, that needs to be done as a sperate [Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) operation:

```cs
await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["{item-id}"]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(new DriveItem
     {
       Name = "new-file-name.docx"
     });
```